# To minimize Javascript and Jquery loading in my webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am doing a School students web project.
I have a menu like below

```
Information     Reports
View            Pass Percentage
Add             Subject Wise Percentage
Edit            Subject Wise Result
Delete
```

I am using `HTML, Java Script and Jquery with Cgi`.

If I click Pass Percentage in Report menu, I am generating a HTML document in Iframe. It will **show as Tab View concept**.
So, If I click Subject Wise Percentage, an another tab will pop up with HTML document in Iframe.

Every Html document generating from server(cgi) has the following model.

```
<--- HTML Starting Tags (Title,Head and etc.,) ---->
<--- Need Jquery and Javascript files ---->
```

> ```
> <--- Contents of Result (With In Body Tag as text Plain from server) --->
> ```

```
<--- Need Jquery and Javascript files ---->
<--- HTML Ending Tags (Body,HTML) ---->
```

In Every report, Only Contents of Result will be change. Other things (Javascript and Jquery) will not be changed at any more.
But In my Iframe concept, Every time when I click the report from Reports menu, Jquery and Javascript files are downloading for every report run.

So I wish to load all Jquery and Javascript contents only one time when I open my webpage.

Whenever I click the report from Reports menu, I should only get Contents of Results from server. Repeatedly It should not download Jquery and Javascript files from server for every report.

How can I do this? Can I do this using only by JavaScript or Jquery?

(or)

What technology or tool do I need to study to do this task?

Comment: You can use AJAX where you can:

Update a web page without reloading the page
Request data from a server - after the page has loaded 
Receive data from a server - after the page has loaded
Send data to a server - in the background

Comment: You could use AJAX to only fetch the part of the content that changes, but it's probably better to just make sure you're setting good `Cache-Control` headers on your JavaScript files so the browser simply caches them. (Then it won't bother re-requesting them from the server after it downloaded them once.)

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you , you don't need to use iframe to do that job , actually it is not suggested to use iframe
you need to use AJAX where you can load from the server without reloading the page.
make the head and tags only in the main page , and in the other pages write only your HTML codes without head , and for each click on menu item use the ajax get methode to load the specific page into a div